# Youtube html5 player API

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube

got a problem with extracting the youtube ID on this code:

```
if (vidInfo[2].indexOf('youtube.com')>=0) {
                   vidInfo=vidId.match(/v=.+$/);
                  vidInfo=String(vidInfo).replace(/v=/g,'');
                  vidstring+=' src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+vidInfo+'&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist='+vidInfo+'" ';
                  vidstring+=' height="350" width="425"></embed></center>';
```

at the moment I use this with the Youtube AS API. 
In order to switch to the html5 player I changed it like this:

```
if (vidInfo[2].indexOf('youtube.com')>=0) {
                   vidInfo=vidId.match(/v=.+$/);
                  vidInfo=String(vidInfo).replace(/v=/g,'');
                  vidstring+=' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vidInfo+'&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist='+vidInfo+'" ';
                  vidstring+=' height="350" width="425"></embed></center>';
```

and put a iframe to it. Unfortunately the player doesn't extract the VIDEO ID as common in the old Player. Can anyone help me please? 
Think is has to be in this part:

```
vidInfo=vidId.match(/v=.+$/);
                  vidInfo=String(vidInfo).replace(/v=/g,'');
```

tried to replace "v" by "embed", "vidId" and tried some url.split action but didn't work. The player always displays "Source: www.youtube.com/watch/undefined. Really dont know why? You can find the function in Action on: http://slicklibary.de/music but still the old player. 
Kind regards
Anil

Solved:

```
vidInfo=vidId.match(/v=.+$/);

    vidInfo=String(vidInfo).replace(/v=/g,'').split('&');

    vidstring='<iframe width="425" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vidInfo[0]+'?rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist='+vidInfo[0]+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;"></iframe>';
```

Many thanks to Genkisan: ericulous.com/2007/06/11/popurls-clone-using-wordpress/